# Scapy, sending, receiving and responding

Tags: python, sockets, scapy

I am currently working on a project where I need to send packets to a particular networking hardware, receive responses back, and generate packets based on the response in real time.

I came across Scapy, and to my understanding it is capable of doing the first two parts: sending and receiving. Is it possible through Python to retrieve the necessary fields in a response and respond back?

Thanks!

Comment: Should be possible, yes. However, if you have not done that in the past, in python or in other language, it may prove tricky and time-consuming.

Comment: Scapy is designed exactly for that, yes. It has built-in support to retrieve individual fields and flags in a well-defined network packet, given that it knows the protocol (or you can define your own protocol).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, you have (at least) two options with Scapy:

The clean one is to create an `AnsweringMachine` that matches your needs (you have several examples in Scapy's code).

The dirty (but maybe quicker if that's what you need) one is to give as `prn` parameter to `sniff()` a function that will receive the packet, craft an answer (or anything you like) and `send()` it on the network.

As an example, this code will send RST-ACK packets to any TCP packet seen with SYN flag on:

```
def rst(p):
    ans = IP(src=p[IP].dst, dst=p[IP].src)/TCP(
        flags='RA',
        sport=p[TCP].dport,
        dport=p[TCP].sport,
        seq = 0,
        ack = p[TCP].seq + 1,
    )
    send(ans, verbose=False)
    return "%s\n => %s" % (p[IP].summary(), ans.summary())

sniff(iface="eth0", filter="tcp and tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn == tcp-syn",
      prn=rst)
```